# Keypress function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, compatibility

i have a function called format(). This function does a format to my input. In google chrome works perfect, but on firefox i have a problem when i try to use 'backspace' key to erase input.

```js
$('#valueInput').keypress(function(event) {
  let key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (((key != 46 || (key == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
      $(this).val().toString().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    (key < 48 || key > 57) ||
    $(this).val().toString().indexOf('.') != -1 &&
    $(this).val().toString().split('.')[1].length >= 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}).on('paste', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="valueInput" type="text" />
```

This function does 3 validations. accept only number and dot, accept only one dot, after inputed dot accept only 8 number decimals.

Comment: "I have a bug" is not a good description of the problem. What is it supposed to do, what does it do instead?

Comment: This function does 3 validations. accept only number and dot, accept only one dot, after inputed dot accept only 8 number decimals.

Comment: Edit the question to add clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your code:

```
if(key == 32) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().length - 1));
}
```

Your code will be like it:

```
    $('#valueInput').keypress(function(event) {
      let key = event.keyCode || event.which;  
      if (((key != 46 || (key == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
      $(this).val().toString().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
      (key < 48 || key > 57) ||
       $(this).val().toString().indexOf('.') != -1 &&
       $(this).val().toString().split('.')[1].length >= 8) {
           if(key == 32) {
               $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().length - 1));
           }
           event.preventDefault();
  }
}).on('paste', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: works great. But i was wondering if there is a better way to do this formatting

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Your way is not incorrect, but, you need to improve your code. You can use a Lib for that like Cleave.js or other one.